# issue to center an horizontal menu due to margin-left

Tags: html, css

I'd like to center my horizontal menu to the middle of the page.

The issue is that due to the `margin-left: 20px` applied to each `li` including the first one, the menu is slightly off by `20px`.

Is there a way to fix that? (e.g. by giving the first `li` a margin left of `0px`)

```css
#carte-des-soins {
  text-align: center;
}
#carte-des-soins ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#carte-des-soins li {
  display: inline;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#carte-des-soins li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="carte-des-soins">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="type-de-soin">
        <a href="#" data-region="soins-1"> Soins 1</a>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="type-de-soin">
        <a href="#" data-region="soins-2"> Soins 2</a>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="type-de-soin">
        <a href="#" data-region="soins-3"> Soins 3</a>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="type-de-soin">
        <a href="#" data-region="soins-4"> Soins 4</a>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#carte-des-soins ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;          /* add */
}

#carte-des-soins li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px;  /* instead of margin-left: 20px */
}
```

Comment: definitely the most logical answer for just centering stuff

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain the rationale behind 0 10Px ? Many thanks

Comment: @Greg `margin: 0 10px` will set `margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px`. Then there is symmetry, so the elements are centered.

Comment: @Greg `0` (AKA 0px) accounts for `top, bottom`, while the next value of `10px` accounts for `right, left`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use the following css

```
#carte-des-soins {
  text-align: center;
}
#carte-des-soins ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#carte-des-soins > ul {
  padding: 0;
}
#carte-des-soins li {
  display: inline;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#carte-des-soins li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#carte-des-soins li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/3ovgghtu/

removed browser default styles

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

and adding `margin-left` to all the childs except the `first-child`

```
#carte-des-soins li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
#carte-des-soins ul{
  margin-left: -20px;
   }
```